# Wordpress PHP - Tags archive not working, fallback to archive.php (custom post type)

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am trying to create a tag.php file for my posts that are tagged. I have created a custom post type where these tags are in. When I create the tag.php (or tag-newest.php for that matter) it does not work and the posts with the tags still uses archive.php. I suspect there is something in my taxonomy that might be wrong but I have not been able to crack it. My custom post type is as follows:

```
function game_review_post_type(){
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Reviews',
            'singular_name' => 'Review',
        ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-widgets-menus',
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),

    );
    register_post_type('reviews', $args);

}
add_action('init', 'game_review_post_type');

// Taxonomy
function game_review_taxonomy(){
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Gametypes',
            'singular_name' => 'Gametype',
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
    );
    register_taxonomy('gametypes', array('reviews'), $args);
}
add_action('init', 'game_review_taxonomy');
```

Under the taxonomy of Gametypes I have created a tag called 'Newest'.
What am I doing wrong that makes tag.php completely useless?

Comment: `tag` is only used for the core taxonomy, AFAIK. See [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png) for custom taxonomies.

Comment: Ahh I see! I'm unfamiliar with how you create a Custom Taxonomy Archive (thats the way you would do it then, right?) Do you know where that information is available? :)

Comment: Here’s the official documentation on the various templates: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/